# How to encrypt and decrypt using public-private key pair using crypto module, not able to decrypt data with private key

Tags: cryptojs

The code snippets to encrypt and decrypt:

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
function ClickToEditCtrl() {
    let data = "sachin123";
    let encryptionKey = "sdfaghjkl";
    let decryptionKey = "cghjkl";

    let encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, encryptionKey);
    let decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData.toString(), decryptionKey);

    console.log("Data:", data);
    console.log("Encrypted data:", encryptedData.toString());
    console.log("Decrypted data:", decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
}

ClickToEditCtrl();
```

we were able to encrypt the data with public key but we are not able to decrypt the encrypted data with private key.I've searched all around and can't really find anything.

Comment: AES is symmetric cryptography and not asymmetric cryptography (or public key cryptography). Also, CryptoJS does not support asymmetric cryptography. You may be confusing this with NodeJS's crypto module, which supports both symmetric and asymmetric cryptography.